# How to jump 2nd index in foreach loop

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach

I am trying to foreach loop. Each index is showing different views. So i must seperate them. I made this.

```
@foreach($videos as $video)

 @if ($loop->first)
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <a href="{{$video->url}}"><img src="{{('/storage/'.$video->thumbnail('top_cropped'))}}" class="embed-responsive" alt=""></a>
    </div>
 @endif
    <div class="col-md-6 col-6 mt-10px">
        <a href="{{$video->url}}"><img src="{{('/storage/'.$video->thumbnail('cropped'))}}" class="embed-responsive" alt=""></a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

In this situtation first div got first value from foreach.

2nd div got first value from foreach. **That is actual problem**.

3nd div got second value from foreach. It must be third.

1st value to 1st div

2nd and 3rd values are going to 2nd div

I need to start foreach loop from second index after $loop->first. I can't figure out the solution.
Also i tried

```
@foreach ($videos as $key => $video)
@if($key > 0)
//Codes
@endif
```

Also this is my controller:

```
$videos = Video::latest()->take(3)->get();
```

I didn't made this. I think this is a common question. But solution is not simple for me yet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already the number of videos you need to display

```
@foreach($videos as $key=> $video)
    @php $modulus = $key%3 @enphp
    @if ($modulus == 0)
        // 1st template
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="{{$video->url}}"><img src="{{('/storage/'.$video->thumbnail('top_cropped'))}}" class="embed-responsive" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    @elseif($modulus == 1)
        // 2nd template
        <div class="col-md-6 col-6 mt-10px">
          <a href="{{$video->url}}"><img src="{{('/storage/'.$video->thumbnail('cropped'))}}" class="embed-responsive" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    @elseif($modulus == 2)
      // third template goes here
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: thats do samething with my $key > 0.
1st div = 1st value.
2nd div = 2nd value and 3rd div = empty. Not override. I dont now why. It must work. Your code is clean.

Comment: Try to use `all` instead of `get`, actually there's no reason that 3rd value goes empty unless if there're less than 3 videos in the database.

Comment: Yes its probably db problem. I will look at. Its working im sure.